# Android DataBinding change typeface of other view on click

Tags: android, data-binding, kotlin

I have a filter bar that shows a separate TextView for each letter ("A", "B","C"...). I want to achive that, when I click on the TextView with `A` it gets bold, and all other TextViews should go back to normal font style. If I then click on `C`, `A` (and all other) TextViews should show normal and "C" should show bold font. 
Is there an efficient way to to this with data binding? I want to avoid to write a LiveData-property for each of the textfields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a `ObservableField<>` with `selectedId` or `selectedText` of the view inside your viewModel, also add a method inside viewModel `changeSelectedValue` and pass view to it, directly from xml `onClick`.

Next, you will have to create custom binding adapter, which will accept your `ObservableField<>` with `selectedId` or `selectedText`, and will check if the value is the same for itself.

So everything can be done with databinding. Do you need some code examples?

Comment: Ah thanks, I didn't think of ObservableField at all. Works like charm.